# pip - how to install a package that requires an older version of pip

Tags: mac, pip, version

I was trying to install `websocket_client` on macOS10.14.5 using `pip3 19.1.1`

```
pip3 install websocket_client
```

but got an error:

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==19.0.3' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

it seemed that my `pip` version is too new to install websocket_client.

so, how can I install it in this situation?

Thanks,

Teddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue here is in installed system pip. You need to reinstall python. And after that do not upgrade pip yourself.

```
brew reinstall python
```